# In linq getting synonym of word

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to get the synonym of word in c#. For instance, merhaba - hello or selam-hi. I can only do "merhaba" to "hello" but i can't access the other nodes.(merhaba-hi or selam-hi)
How can i do this ?
Thanks.

My XML file.

```
<Words>
    <Meaning>
        <Turkish type="noun">merhaba</Turkish>
        <Turkish type="noun">selam</Turkish>
        <English type="noun">hello</English>
        <English type="noun">hi</English>
    </Meaning>
</Words>
```

My query was like that.

```
var word = from p in doc.Elements("Words").Elements("Meaning")
             where textBox1.Text == p.Element("Turkish").Value
             select new
             {
                _word = p.Element("Turkish").Value,
                meaning = p.Element("English").Value,
                kind = p.Element("English").Attribute("type").Value
             };
```

Comment: First thing I'd like to note is that this XML is not very suited for what you want. There is no direct correlation between "hello - merhaba" other than that they happen to be both the first word in the list of words for that language. This is definetly not the way to go. So unless this XML is from an external source and you can't get them to change it; change the XML.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are actually trying to do here. Do you want to get all the nodes under <Meaning> no matter which of the variations you get as input? I agree that the XML structure seems a bit too flat to do this in a clear way.

Comment: Ex. User inputs "merhaba" and i want to show him hello and hi. This code only brings me hello. I cant access the other node which names the same(english).So what im gonna do ? :) Should I change the "English" to other place ?

Comment: @RobIII: In this case all four words mean the same thing which is why they are under the same meaning node. It may not be perfect but the correlation is that they are all in the same node and there is no more or less correlation between hello-salem, hi-merhaba, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to try something like this:

```
var word = from p in doc.Elements("Words").Elements("Meaning")
           where p.Elements("Turkish").Any(item => item.Value == textBox1.Text)
           from synonym in p.Elements("English")
           select new
           {
               _word = textBox1.Text,
               meaning = synonym.Value,
               kind = synonym.Attribute("type").Value
           };
```

The expression `p.Elements("Turkish").Any(item => item.Value == textBox1.Text)` looks for a meaning element that contains the desired word. The `from synonym in p.Elements("English")` line runs through all elements with the name `English`.

Comment: I can access from the "merhaba" to all but cant accsess for "selam". It dont read for the second node

Comment: @user1545283 I've changed the where clause to do what I think you want it to do. If this is not what you want, it'd be nice if you could clarify what the desired behavior is.

Comment: That's what i what. Thanks for your interest.I corrected my query and it's working now:) I create a new "from synonym in element Turkish" and send it to the where block. .. || p.Elements("Turkish").. like that. Anyway I am appreciated for your help. Thanks again :)